# Woody stemmed plant with variegated palmate leaves

Tags: identification

[image]

Please help me to identify this plant that I bought

Answer (score 8):

It is a variegated version of Schefflera arboricola; as such it is a generally smaller plant than the plain green version. It will grow outdoors as long as temperatures are not less than 25 degF for any length of time, but is more often grown as a houseplant; grown in the ground outdoors in areas with a suitable climate, it may reach 8-12 feet, but will be smaller contained in a pot. Needs a soil which drains freely, and should only be watered (in a pot) when the surface of the potting compost is dry to the touch; when you do water, water well, such that water drains from the bottom of the pot. More info can be found here: [Variegated Schefflera](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/care-outdoor-variegated-schefflera-39557.html).

Comment: On wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schefflera_arboricola   Wikimedia also has a nice picture: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Schefflera_arboricola-yercaud-salem-India.JPG

Comment: @Ken Graham Thanks for all the great editing you're doing. It really helps a lot!